# Symfony 3, удалить записи из двух таблиц

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3, doctrine2

Здравствуйте, мне нужно удалить записи из двух таблиц. Есть таблица orders которая связана по типу один ко многим с таблицей order_item.
Нужно по некоторой выборке записей из orders удалить соответствующие запитси в order_item.

```
public function deleteOrders()
{
    $dayClear = new DateTime('-2 days');

    return
        $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->delete('AdminBundle:Order', 'o')
            ->delete('AdminBundle:OrderItem', 'oi')
            ->leftJoin('AdminBundle:OrderItem', 'oi', 'WITH', 'oi.order_id = o.id')

            ->where('o.total IS NULL')
            ->andWhere('o.updated <= :dayClear')
            ->setParameter('dayClear', $dayClear)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

}
```

Я реализовал такой метод для удаления. но он не рабочий, при этом когда я комментирую строку

```
->delete('AdminBundle:OrderItem', 'oi')
```

то данные из первой таблице удаляются.
В чем может быть проблема и как решить задачу? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если реализовывать через `DQL`, думаю проще будет в первую очередь нужно найти ids. И потом  можно сделать приблизительно так:

```
 $this->createQueryBuilder('o')
        ->delete()
         ->from('AdminBundle:Order o, AdminBundle:OrderItem oi')
        ->whereIn('o.id', '?', $ids)
        ->whereIn('o.order_id', '?', $ids)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: как вариант да, сначала сделать выборку по всем заказам которые удолетворяют условиям, сделай из их id  массив и потом использовать. Спасибо!